# Navigation in Html5Mode on and off

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Html5Mode in AngularJS only when it's available. However I don't know the proper way to use  tags to navigate in the app in both ways:

```
<a href="#/foo">Works in regular mode</a>
<a href="/foo">Works in Html5Mode</a>
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, if html5 mode is enabled and a browser doesn't support it, it falls back to the hash

Comment: Yes but in that case how to configure the href to works in both modes?

Answer (score 0):

You are write about the href but html5mode won't help you without doing URL Rewriting.

Comment: So if I would like to work with both enabled and disabled I can't use direct link with <a> tags without rewrite the links for each situation?

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="/foo">link name</a>` will work in both instances. Like I said in the comment, if your browser doesn't support html5mode it will gracefully fallback and force a browse to `#/foo`